# Does QSettings write the settings file again, even if contents are not changed?

Tags: qt4

For the following code, in the destructor function of a class:

```
QSettings sets;
sets.setValue ("Category/Name", "abc");
```

Will the settings file get written again?

Or should I do this to reduce disk access:

```
if (sets.value ("Category/Name") != "abc") 
   sets.setValue (...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `QSettings::setValue` will force a write to the settings file even if the setting has not changed.  As such, if you are trying to prevent writes to the settings file, your second approach is advisable.